# two conditions checking in where clause using linq 2 entites

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

hi i have table called products with columns

```
                 product_id
                 prodcut_name
                 prodcut_price( values like 1200,2000,3000,100)
                 prodcut_desc
                 category_id(1,2,3,.....)
```

anorther table  categories with columns

```
              category_id(1,2,3.......)
              category_name(a,b,c....)
```

and entity name is dbcontext...

How can i get the products with category name   "a" and product price is  >500 and <10000

i am using linq to enitities...

would any pls help on this..one ....

Many thanks....

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are looking for logic operators, and these are the ones you are going to use in c#:

- `&&` logical `AND`
- `||` logical `OR`
- `!` logical `NOT`
- `^` logical (bitwise) `XOR`
- `COND ? TRUE-STATEMENT : FALSE-STATEMENT` ternary operator

So your composite condition in pseudo code going to look like:

```
product_price > 500 AND product_price < 10000
```

Now, if you have no foreign key in DB, when you've created your context it only going to have DBSets, and they are not going to have navigation properties. So your only option is to use Cubicle.Jockey's answer.

If you have foreign keys in DB, you will have navigation properties on your entity objects and you will be able to do the following:

```
var query = from p in dbcontext.products
where p.category.name == 'a' 
   && p.product_price > 500 
   && p.product_price < 10000
select p;
```

Alternatively you can use LINQ extension methods directly:

```
  var query = dbcontext.Products.Where(p => p.category.name == 'a' 
                                         && p.product_price > 500 
                                         && p.product_price < 10000);
```

If you need a list or array and want close dbcontext you are calling either `ToList` or `ToArray` on `query`:

```
var products = query.ToList();
```

There is alternative way of doing it with Entity Framework (EF) - build-in [EntitySQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387129(v=vs.110).aspx) query language. You are going to have similar expression with it:

```
var query = ProductsQuery.Where("it.Category.Name == 'a' AND it.Product_Price BETWEEN 500 AND 10000");
```

where `ProductsQuery` is `ObjectQuery<Product>`.

Comment: For your version would he need to do
dbcontext.products.Include("category")?

Comment: op: if you created you generated typed DataContext after adding foreign keys , this navigation properities just exist for you

Comment: Cubicle.Jockey: he doens't. first `Include` is for EF not Linq2Sql, second - you don't need to include it when setting condition for query, however you'll need to call `LoadWith` for Linq2Sql query in order to eager load category together with products

Comment: And yes your are correct I was just in another thing about EF and it stuck...my bad.

Comment: @vittore .....so how can i select the all other fields like product_name and prodcut_description,product_price to gether also with these conditions...would you pls suggest.. why i am asking this .. i need to popualte this details on datagrid view....using lambda expressions....

Comment: you just have you list or array of Product objects, obviously you are going to bind data source of datagrid to this list or array. you are accessing properties of product the same way you did it in your linq query - nothing else

Comment: @vittore can i directly assign the query result to datagrid view datasource like this.... datagridview1.datasource = query ??

Comment: @rockyashkumar: i think you've tried it already, but yes you can, moreover you can assign datasource to both query and query.ToList() depending on what are you going to achive

Answer (score 5):

```
from p in dbcontext.products
join c in dbcontext.category on p.category_id equals c.category_id
where p.product_price > 500 && p.product_price < 10000 && c.Name == "a"
select p
```

This will return you an IQueryable with the filtered results.

Based on Vittore's answer below, if there is a foreign key constraints this would be the more appropriate version:

```
from p in dbcontext.products
where p.category.name =='a' && p.product_price > 500 && p.product_price < 10000
select p;
```

Comment: you forget about category name

Answer (score 1):

join the product and categories tables on `category_id` and then use a `where` to filter out `product_price`.