# Using multiple clauses in where

Tags: c#, linq

What is the correct way to include multiple wheres in a LINQ call for OR

```
List<Pos> posList = DbContext.PosList
                             .Where<Pos>(p => p.Pos == "51000785" || 
                                         p => p.Pos == "123")
                             .ToList<Pos>();
```

Comment: You can just remove the second `p =>` - it's already been defined

Comment: Doing a simple google search `using two conditions in LINQ where clause` brings up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7289565/465053), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10333732/465053), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11314203/465053) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8755176/465053) SO link. All will be helpful to get you an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Linq where clause takes one expression and returns one bool value. Yours is taking two expressions each with their own return value. You would need to combine these two into one lambda expression that returns one value rather than the two separate ones in your example.

```
List<Pos> posList = DbContext.PosList
         .Where<Pos>(p => p.Pos == "51000785" || p.Pos == "123")
         .ToList<Pos>();
```

Comment: Good edit. Hopefully whoever downvoted you will return and remove it.

Comment: Jolly Good old chap!